# I am facing an issue when sending email in asp.net (C#). The issue does not occur when using gmail or hotmail config

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

i have attached the code here:

```
string from = "name@comapanydomain.com";

string to = "name@comapanydomain.com";
string subject = "Employer request form";
string body = "body";
string senderEmail = "un";
string senderPassword = "password";


MailMessage o = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body.ToString());
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient();
smtpobj.Host = "ip address(e.g:192.232.122.232)";
smtpobj.Port = 25;

smtpobj.EnableSsl = false;
smtpobj.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpobj.Credentials = netCred;
smtpobj.Send(o);
```

The email service provider ->rapid cloud and
               domain name provider -> godaddy.

the email config was provided by rapid cloud , 
the config works with outlook when sending email but not in website. I have attached the error as well.Please assist. [error that i am getting:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vhf5.png)Thank you

Comment: see this if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025633/c-sharp-smtp-godaddy-send-email

Comment: Please add the actual error to your question, rather than providing a link to an image that may disappear later.

Comment: @Valkyriee : The link guides on using godaddy smtp, but in this case, only the domain is hosted in godaddy but the email service provider is different(Rapid Cloud) .thank you

Comment: @hellofriends false both smtpobj.EnableSsl &
smtpobj.UseDefaultCredentials.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the port number. It may be something other than 25

Comment: Ive already checked in telnet.it does give response..and it works in outlook as well..would it be error in the code...?is there any other suggestion in implementing this?