# SmtpClient.send method threw "Failure sending mail" exception

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

My mail program works on 2 boxes but throws "Failure sending mail" exception on the other box. This exception message is not very descriptive. Is there a way to dump the exception trace for the ease of debugging as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209617/smtpclient-failure-sending-mail)?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrap the bad code in a try{}catch(exception e){} and set a break point in the body of the catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to log the exception because it's running on a different box. You could look at [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

At it's simplest you can just write a text file to the file system

```
try
{
     // Your mail code here

}
catch (Exception ex)
{     
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\log.txt");
    file.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    file.Close();
}
```

You aren't guaranteed a particularly helpful stack trace, and you might want to log other bits of information from the exception as well. Last time I encountered this problem it was firewall rules that prevented contacting the host.

Comment: Thanks. Does the stack trace help in the case that the SMTP traffic gets blocked by the firewall rules?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, it was probably a message more like 'Cannot contact host'. If you want you can log every non null property of the exception to the file to help diagnose it.